# Flutter : Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to learn firebase with flutter and i ran into this problem
here is my code :

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('attendees')
            .doc(user.uid)
            .snapshots()
            .listen((snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data() != null) {
            if (snapshot.data()!['attending']) {
              _attending = Attending.yes;
            } else {
              _attending = Attending.no;
            }
          } else {
            _attending = Attending.unknown;
          }
          notifyListeners();
        });
```

what is the solution ?
the exact problem is within this line :
if (snapshot.data()!['attending']) {

how can I rewrite this so i wont ruin the current functionality ?
I appreciate  your help inadvance

Comment: what exact error statement are you getting? I dont think the problem is in the line `snapshot.data()!=null`

Comment: Im really sorry ..i was tried and made a mistake please check the question  again

Comment: Probably the issue is in this line `snapshot.data()!['attending']`, what is the value of `snapshot.data()!['attending']` ? cast that value to a bool and use that

Comment: yes it is .... could you please provide the code ? I dont get it like this  ..

Comment: I have tried to put it in a boolean variable but it gives an error that says you cant assign a dynamic variable to a boolean one ...so i deleted.

Comment: @delaram what exactly is `[attending]` , is it stored in firebase? 1. You are accessing it wrongly 2. `Conditions must have static type bool`  you are getting this error because you are not doing condition checking as `= sign` is missing

Comment: atending is a boolean  variable ....check this link : https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-get-to-know-flutter#8      im trying to understand the firebase codelab .... and this problem hasnt ocuured in their code anyway if you found somthing let me know ...this part of code is in their 9th step

Comment: @delaram check my answer.

Comment: @delaram did you check my answer ? Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: @delaram you first need to understand the error and that's why I have explained in detail why that error is occuring. Hope it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are getting error  -

> Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'

because on line `snapshot.data()!['attending']` an `= sign` is missing.

To make your code work just do

```
if (snapshot.data() != snapshot.data()!['attending']) {
              _attending = Attending.yes;
            } else {
              _attending = Attending.no;
            }
```

---

## Understanding The Error

I would also like to point out that `Dart` a stricter language (more like Java in terms of **'truthy' values**).

In JavaScript you can use any **‘truthy’ value** in a conditional statement. In Dart you **cannot** use **‘truthy’ values**. For example:

```
var name = 'Joe';
if (name) {
  // do something...
```

OR

```
var a = 1
if(a){
//this would work in JavaScript
}
```

---

You cannot do such things in `Java` or `Dart`. The reason is that `Dart` requires that a condition is a bool true not just a **'truthy' value**. You could correct the code by changing it to:

```
if (name.isNotEmpty)
```

OR

```
if(a==1)
{
//these == signs are really important
}
```

Comment: Hi Now i understand the error better but when i tried it I got and error that says : data isnt defined so I changed it into this line :  if (snapshot.data() != snapshot.data()!['attending']) {     now i see a bug in my code ... let me fix it then i will let know about the result the problem is within the firebase code lab in this link :  https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-get-to-know-flutter#8

Comment: @delaram hi, can you please quote the error message?

Comment: @delaram I am glad that you are now able to understand the error. Understanding Errors are first step towards the solution

Comment: they shouldnt enage a beginner with these problems ...Im going to send this link to our fellows out there thats why im trying to completely soleve the problem ....i really appreciate your effort here.

Comment: @delaram why are you doing `(snapshot.data() != snapshot.data()!['attending'])` ? Change it to simply  `(snapshot.data() != data['attending'])`.

Comment: @delaram why aren't you doing it the same way as the codelab?

Comment: ```int _attendees = 0;
int get attendees => _attendees;

Attending _attending = Attending.unknown;
StreamSubscription<DocumentSnapshot>? _attendingSubscription;
Attending get attending => _attending;
set attending(Attending attending) {
  final userDoc = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('attendees')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
  if (attending == Attending.yes) {
    userDoc.set({'attending': true});
  } else {
    userDoc.set({'attending': false});
  }
}```

Comment: @delaram check `lib.dart` mentioned there

Comment: I have done the same thing  but im still checking if something is missing

Comment: @delaram kindly implement the say way as mentioned in codelab. And if this answer helped you kindly accept it as this might help future developers. I would request you to understand the error and move on to implementing the same way as mentioned in codelab

Comment: @delaram you can find whole code [here](https://github.com/flutter/codelabs/tree/master/firebase-get-to-know-flutter/step_09)

Comment: Hi bro i have successfully fixed the bug to check your answer as the right answer for this question please change your that line of your answer to this one : if (snapshot.data() != snapshot.data()!['attending']) {   now everything works perfect !!!! Im so happy about it ....your time and your effort really meant a lot to me  thank youuuuu.

Comment: @delaram thats great , I have edited the answer for future developers

Answer (score 1):

Just store the `snapshot.data()` to the local map variable and do the operations by that.

```dart
    _attendingSubscription = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('attendees')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {
      final Map<String, dynamic>? data = snapshot.data();
      if (data != null) {
        _attending = data['attending'] ? Attending.yes : Attending.no;
      } else {
        _attending = Attending.unknown;
      }
      notifyListeners();
    });
```

Comment: Im really sorry bro ...i mentioned the wrong line the problem is within this line : if (snapshot.data()!['attending']) {     please check the question again  I was tried and didnt see the line correctly

Comment: It's okay brother. I have modified the code snippets. Please check.

Comment: I really appreciate your attention ...as it is killing me from last night .. i have tried your code but still getting this error : Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'.   check this link : https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-get-to-know-flutter#8 maybe it help you find the answer im trying to understand the firebase code lab ....BTW I could be your sister ..hahahaha

Comment: Could you please tell me the data type of the `snapshot.data()['attendance']`?